# Login com ActiveDirectory

Tags: php, javascript, windows, servidor, active-directory

Estou tentando realizar a conexão com AD. Porém o erro é exibido:

> Warning: ldap_connect(): Could not create session handle: Bad
>   parameter to an ldap routine in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\my portable
>   files\ad\ad.php on line 8
>       Could not connect to LDAP server.

Alguém saberia as possíveis causas para essa falha na conexão?

```
<?php
$ldap_server = "192.168.2.1/nomeservidor";
$dominio = "DOMINIO/";
$user = $dominio."administrador";

echo $user;

$ldap_porta = "389";
$ldap_pass   = "minhasenha";
$ldapcon = ldap_connect($ldap_server, $ldap_porta) or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");

if ($ldapcon) {
  $bind = ldap_bind($ldapcon, $user, 'minhaSenha');
  if ($bind) {
    echo "LDAP bind successful…";
  }
  else {
    echo "LDAP bind failed…";
  }
}
?>
```

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Não conheco de PHP, mais pode ser que [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232950/php-ldap-connection) possa te ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar a sua url de conexão assim:
$ldap_server = "ldap://192.168.2.1/nomeservidor";

Ou então, coloque o número da porta após o ip:

192.168.2.1:porta

Referência:
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ldap-connect.php